# crossing edges in the travelling salesman problem

Tags: algorithm, theory, graph-theory

Does there exist a travelling salesman problem where the optimal solution has edges that cross?

The nodes are in an x-y plane, so crossing in this case means if you were to draw the graph, two line segments connecting four separate nodes would intersect.

Comment: Define edges that cross, please.

Comment: If edges cross, then each node is location dependent. Essentially that means a crossing edge is a node, and thus changes the perspective of what the optimal solution is.

Comment: Because if two aircraft flight paths cross, you can always hop between planes half way?

Comment: @Pete Kirkham, what is your point?

Comment: @Pindatjuh Airports/flights are an example of a graph to input into a TSP solver where crossing edges do not introduce a node.

Comment: @bob The answer to this question is entirely dependent on two pieces of information you do not provide - whether you are using a Euclidian metric, and whether you can consider any crossing of edges a node. If you have a Eucidean metric but no change at crossings ( eg a flat-earth airline with a fixed set of flights between cities ) then there are examples with crossings, if you have other metrics with implicit nodes at crossing there are again examples, but if you have both Eucildian metric and implicit nodes at all crossings then lhf's reasoning applies.

Answer (score 14):

If two edges in a closed polygonal line cross, then there is a polygonal line with the same vertices but with smaller perimeter. This is a consequence of the triangle inequality. So, a solution to the TSP must be a simple polygon. See [this article](http://www.ams.org/featurecolumn/archive/tsp.html) (Figure 4).

Comment: Question: As part of the traveling salesman tour, isn't it necessary that the last city visited connect back to the first city visited, and in this way that last path 'intersects'/crosses multiple previous edges? Edit: Maybe it depends on how you draw it? Like there is a way to draw it as a polygon without intersecting edges.

Comment: @Jason, the point of my answer is the for the Euclidean TSP, the solution never crosses itself.

Comment: Just in case the article moves: ["Sales and Chips" in: Feature Column from the AMS](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-tsp)

Answer (score 3):

If you consider a non-Euclidean metric like L1 (Manhattan distance), then it's pretty easy to  construct shortest tours that self-intersect.

```
+--3--+
|  |  |
|  |  |
2--+--1
|  |  |
|  |  |
+--4--+
```

If each neighboring pair of intersections is at distance 1, then all tours have length 8, including the self-intersecting one that goes 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 1.

Comment: However, I believe this could be translated into a travelling salesman problem in a 3-D euclidian space, in which case the optimal solution (equivalent to this one), would have no crossings. The key to my addition is that all NP complete problems - including the manhattan distance TSP problem - can be "reduced" to one another. So solving manhattan TSP is no different than solving euclidian TSP... and in euclidian TSP, no optimal solution will have an edge crossing.

Answer (score 2):

You could get crossing edges if the cost of going from node A->C plus the cost B->D  > cost A->B and C->D. You might get this when the cost in not propertional to the distance between the nodes.

A real life example might be that there is a bonus from going from A to C (for example you can smuggle some contrabande) or the cost is dependant on the previous steps (turing left a traffic lights might cost you a lot of time).

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, any connected graph where every node has two edges has only one TPS solution, and if drawn with crossings will meet your stated criteria.

If you put other constraints, such as if you were modelling travelling around the globe using trade winds, so costs are only somewhat related to position in space, you might find a more complex case where crossing is optimal.

Comment: "connected graph where every node has two edges" is a circle, isn't it?